# Can I setup convention AutoMapper properties

Tags: automapper

I'm making extensive use of Markdown in a new project that I'm working on, and I would love to be able to configure an AutoMapper convention that maps all instances of Property X to XMarkdown, and converts the resultant output to Markdown.

So, if I give any destination string property the suffix Markdown and the source is a string then I want to transform the output.

p.s. I know how to render Markdown, so what I'm really after is the convention to get AutoMapper to take the tedium away for me.  Thanks.

Comment: did you had a chance to look at Convention Mapping (Properties that are matched via convention) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If things are really consistent, like FirstNameMarkdown, you can use some built in functions.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.RecognizeDestinationPostfixes(new[] { "Markdown" }));
```

Comment: Given a function X(string) -> mardown, how do I plug into the framework to do the translation?